# alguien que tenga una manera análoga de hacer lo mismo que hace esta función recursiva

Tags: python, revisión-de-código

**código:**
instrucciones: Para esto deberás crear la función recursiva final_battle.

final_battle(frases, vida): Esta función recursiva recibe dos parámetros: frases [str] y vida [int], y retorna un string correspondiente a la frase final de Ramsey.
El primero será un string compuesto por varias frases separadas por ";" y el segundo corresponde a los puntos de vida que posees al inicio de la batalla. Tu vida va a ir disminuyendo una cantidad igual al largo de cada frase de Ramsey, y en el caso de que una frase contenga un "!" al final, la vida se disminuye en el doble del largo de la frase.

Tu objetivo es ir imprimiendo cada frase en una línea junto con la vida que te queda luego del daño de la frase. Mientras tengas vida y queden frases disponibles, deberás imprimir una a una cada frase y disminuir la vida como se especificó anteriormente.

Cuando te quedes sin vida, o Ramsey se quede sin frases, debes retornar la frase correspondiente y terminar la recursión. En el caso de que el largo de la última frase de Ramsey sea mayor a tu vida restante, debes dejar vida igual a 0.

La explicación de los print están especificados en Output Format.

```py
def final_battle(frases, vida):
    #primera vez, si entra string pasarlo a lista
    if type(frases)==str:
        frases=frases.split(";")
        
    if frases==[] or vida==0:
        return "YOU &@$#/ DONKEY!"
    if frases==[] and vida>0:
        return "Oh dear, oh dear, gorgeous"
        
    frase=frases.pop(0)
    if vida-len(frase)>0 and frase[len(frase)-1]!="!":
        vida-=len(frase)
    elif vida-2*len(frase)>0 and frase[len(frase)-1]=="!":
        vida-=2*len(frase)     
    else:
        vida=0
    print(f"{frase} Vida actual: {vida}")
    
    return final_battle(frases,vida)

final_battle('ESTA MUY DULCE;PESIMA PRESENTACION',34)
print()
final_battle('MI ABUELA COCINA MEJOR;ESTA SECO!',40)
```

**output:**

```
ESTA MUY DULCE Vida actual: 20
PESIMA PRESENTACION Vida actual: 1

MI ABUELA COCINA MEJOR Vida actual: 18
ESTA SECO! Vida actual: 0
'YOU &@$#/ DONKEY!'
```

Comment: cual es el problema que tienes? o solo quieres saber si hay una mejor forma de hacerlo?

Comment: quiero saber si hay una mejor manera de hacerlo :)

Comment: ok, en primer lugar tu código esta mal indentado. Ya lo indente bien

Comment: jajaj gracias eso cuando lo copio aquí que se me cambia, si encuentras otra manera de hacerlo por favor avísame estaré atenta

Comment: pues creo que todo esta bien :)

Comment: lograste encontrar otra manera??

Comment: Noup, como dije todo esta bien

Comment: Hay alguna mejora que se puede hacer. Pero, ¿por qué no quieres recursividad? ¿Tienes problemas para terminar la recursividad y por eso buscas otra cosa?